# How do I visit SSL website created in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2010

Hello I have recently installed SharePoint Server 2010 and have successfully created two web site collections. One that hosts the main team site for the organisation I work for and the other to host the MySites.

I am trying to create one individual website that uses SSL. When creating the website I create give it port 667 and enable the Use SSL radio button on the create web application form. Next to the Use SSL question there is a comment:

*"If you choose to use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), you must add the certificate on each server using the IIS administration tools.  Until this is done, the web application will be inaccessible from this IIS Web Site."*

So I complete the form and wait for SharePoint to create the site and it gives me a URL of https://staging001:667 and so on the SharePoint Server machine I go into IIS and create a self signed certificate. Next I try to apply the certificate to the site that has just been created in IIS by clicking on Bindings and then adding a new binding with HTTPS protocol and setting the port number this time to be 997. Note that I didn't remove or edit the existing HTTPS binding set on that site. Also the reason I am using pors 667 and 997 are because ports 80 and 443 are already used by other websites on the same server.

I do add the site to a new site collection in SharePoint through the central administration website.

I apply the new Binding and restart the web application in IIS. I then try going to "https://sipstaging001:667" and I can't get to the site and so I then try "https://sipstaging001:997" and have the same problem.

Please could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or guide me on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable SSL during creation of the web application, the port you entered (667) is the SSL port. So after creation you have to go to IIS Manager and select the existing binding for port 667 and add the certificate to that one.
If you choose another port (997 in your case) SharePoint doesn't know about it. If you want to do that, go to Central Admin and add an alternate access mapping to that port.

marco